# How to create the file in azure storage blob using SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, azure, azure-sql-database

I am looking for an approach to create the file in the azure blob storage using SQL server Stored procedure.

I tried to use below approach

```
CREATE CREDENTIAL indcredential   
WITH IDENTITY= 'storage account name', -- this is the name of the storage account you specified when creating a storage account   
SECRET = 'key1'

BACKUP DATABASE ILS
TO URL = 'blobpath/dbbackup.bacpac' 
/* URL includes the endpoint for the BLOB service, followed by the container name, and the name of the backup file*/ 
WITH CREDENTIAL = 'indcredential' ;
/* name of the credential you created in the previous step */ 
GO
```

Using the above code , I am able to create the db backup file dbbackup.bacpac in azure storage.

Any idea how to create the simple text file in azure blob path ?

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/create-external-file-format-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017

Comment: https://docs.qubole.com/en/latest/user-guide/analyze/tsql.html

Comment: Is this SQL Server running on an Azure Virtual Machine?  If so please remove the `azure-sql-database` tag.

Comment: @DavidBrowne-Microsoft Its a sql database service I am consuming. not running on any azure virtual machine

Comment: I was asking because you can't run BACKUP DATABASE unless you're on Azure SQL Database Managed Instance, and then it has to be a COPY_ONLY backup.  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/backup-transact-sql?view=azuresqldb-mi-current  And in any case BACKUP DATABASE creates a .bak file not a .bacpac file.

Comment: @DavidBrowne-Microsoft it is just for reference I provided. Please let me know if you have solution for my problem, Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

> I am looking for an approach to create the file in the azure blob storage using SQL server Stored procedure.

There's no direct way to do this.  You can [read](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/import-export/examples-of-bulk-access-to-data-in-azure-blob-storage?view=sql-server-2017) files from BLOB storage, but not write them.  Instead, you can use an [Azure Function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-overview), or perhaps a [Logic App](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/services/logic-apps/) to copy data from Azure SQL Database to Azure Storage.

Comment: I was able to write file to blob by mapping the storage blob path to local.

Comment: From your client program, using someething like `azure-storage-fuse`? https://github.com/Azure/azure-storage-fuse

Comment: No. Any other solution ?